# How to use price guarantees in Patrician 4?

Tags: patrician-iv

In [Patrician 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrician_IV), once you have been elected Lord Mayor, it is possible to create a list of items whose price is guaranteed by the city treasury. If I understand correctly, this means that the treasury will fund the difference between the guaranteed and the market price. How can this be used to one's advantage?

Comment: I would say that depends a lot on the circumstances. Let's assume for example that you achieve this in a large and sprawling city that is way ahead of other cities in terms of citizens and production - meaning it will produce more for less currency on average. Here you can use a price guarantee to get a stable supply of goods for the reduced big-city price to sell elsewhere for higher small-city prices.
Just one example application, there's more depending on the state of the game.